# need to call an array and print it in a different class

Tags: java

so I have a stock program that has symbols stored in an array, I need to call that array into a different class and print it out. This is my code and the array code.

```
abstract class stockArray
{

   String stocks[];

   String stockSymbols[] ={ "SMG", "APL", "GE", "TOY","SUB","GM","LG","VZ","JP","BTN"};

}
```

This is the code where I need to call it and print it CASE 1 of my Switch case statement.  How do I call that array to that location(case 1) and print the contents of that array? Thanks

```
 public class stockProgram  
 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
     {

       String s;

      Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner dec = new Scanner(System.in);       

    System.out.println("Welcome to the stock tracker Program,");

    System.out.println("What would you like to do?");

    System.out.println("***MENU OPTIONS***");

    System.out.println("1. See a list of stocks");
    System.out.println("2. Buy stocks");
    System.out.println("3. Sell Stock Holdings.");
    System.out.println("4. Search Stock listings");
    System.out.println("5. Exit Program");

    System.out.println(" Please Enter an option");        

    int op = sc.nextInt();
        switch(op)
    {


      case 1: System.out.println("---Stock Holdings List---");
              System.out.println("These are the current stocks avaliable to purchase in this program.");

     break;
```

Comment: You can't "call" an array. I think you meant to say "I need to **pass** that array into a different class"

Comment: `stockArray` class is abstract, it can not be used in its current state.

Comment: Don't use multiple Scanner for same input, use only one

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please follow naming convention - class names start with upper-case, so change `stockArray` to `StockArray`.

One way to access that array is to make it `static` like so:-

```
static final String stockSymbols[] ={ "SMG", "APL", "GE", "TOY","SUB","GM","LG","VZ","JP","BTN"};
```

and then use this code in your case statement:-

```
String symbols[] = StockArray.stockSymbols;
Arrays.stream(symbols).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or if you don't want to make it static, you can create an anonymous inner class:-

```
String symbols[] = new StockArray() {}.stockSymbols;
Arrays.stream(symbols).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note that I am storing that array in another variable `symbols` just for demonstration purpose, you don't need to do that.

Comment: Does `StockArray` need to be made non-abstract?

Comment: @ScaryWombat good point, not sure why would the OP have an abstract class without any abstract methods. If there are no hidden methods there, then I would advocate to make it non-abstract; and then there would be no need for anonymous inner class.

Comment: Hey Kartik thanks for the help so I did the first thing you recommended and made it static but I'm getting an error Illegal static declaration in inner class StockProgram.StockArray modifier static is only allowed in constant variable declarations

Comment: @MattLoadman Ah so you have `StockArray` class inside `StockProgram` class. In that case, replace the word `abstract` with `static` because you need to call it from the `main` method. Then access it using `String symbols[] = new Test().stockSymbols;`

Answer (score 0):

Define a class which *extends* the abstract class `stockArray`:

```
class StockArraySubclass extends stockArray {
}
```

Use the `StockArraySubclass` in the `stockProgram` class's switch-case:

```
StockArraySubclass st = new StockArraySubclass();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(st.stockSymbols));
```

This will print: `[SMG, APL, GE, TOY, SUB, GM, LG, VZ, JP, BTN]`